# pyqt phonon videoplayer is a black square

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, phonon

I'd like to have a little quicktime player in my GUI. Here is how I construct it:

```
   videoPlayer = phonon.Phonon.VideoPlayer()
   url = QtCore.QUrl('/home/sslade/waterfalls.mov')
   mediaSource = phonon.Phonon.MediaSource(url)
   videoPlayer.play(mediaSource)
   infoLayout.addWidget(videoPlayer)
```

All other widgets on 'infoLayout' come through just fine, but the videoPlayer shows up as a black rectangle, not even in the aspect ration of the quicktime.

It works if the source is a .png file instead of a .mov file. But Quicktime is listed in my avilableMimeTypes so I figure I'm okay. Check it out:

```
application/annodex
application/x-annodex
audio/annodex
audio/x-annodex
video/annodex
video/x-annodex
video/msvideo
video/x-msvideo
audio/x-aiff
audio/aiff
audio/x-pn-aiff
audio/x-flac
audio/flac
audio/x-realaudio
audio/basic
audio/x-basic
audio/x-pn-au
audio/x-tta
audio/tta
audio/x-mod
audio/mod
audio/it
audio/x-it
audio/x-stm
audio/x-s3m
audio/s3m
application/playerpro
application/adrift
audio/med
audio/x-amf
audio/x-xm
audio/xm
application/ogg
application/x-ogg
application/x-ogm
application/x-ogm-audio
application/x-ogm-video
audio/ogg
audio/x-ogg
video/ogg
video/x-ogg
audio/x-pn-realaudio
audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin
audio/x-real-audio
application/vnd.rn-realmedia
image/png
image/x-png
video/mng
video/x-mng
video/x-flic
video/quicktime
video/x-quicktime
audio/x-m4a
application/x-quicktimeplayer
video/mp4
audio/mp4
audio/x-8svx
audio/8svx
audio/x-16sv
audio/168sv
image/x-ilbm
image/ilbm
video/x-anim
video/anim
video/x-flv
video/flv
application/x-flash-video
video/mkv
video/x-matroska
video/x-ms-asf
video/x-ms-wmv
audio/x-ms-wma
application/vnd.ms-asf
application/x-mplayer2
video/x-ms-asf-plugin
video/x-ms-wvx
video/x-ms-wax
audio/x-wav
audio/wav
audio/x-pn-wav
audio/x-pn-windows-acm
audio/musepack
audio/x-musepack
audio/x-wavpack
audio/x-flac
audio/flac
audio/x-vorbis+ogg
application/ogg
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is that a correct way of making a local file URL in Qt? Try creating it with [fromLocalFile()](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QUrl.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile) instead.

Comment: i just tried fromLocalFile(), no dice. also, i know the way i'm making QUrl's will work because it works with a .png file, just not a .mov file.

Comment: Works for me on linux using the gstreamer backend. Are you sure you've got all the necessary plugins installed?

Comment: i'm not. a failed backend of some kind is my hunch. i will probably have to recompile phonon against something or other.